# Add to the django request.user variable

Tags: python, django, authentication

In django, I use the authenticate() function to log users in. Using `request.user`, I can access the logged in user's information which is pulled from the users table. If I do `request.user.id`, I can get the user's id. In any template, on any request, I can do `user.username` to get the username.

Is there a way by which I can add values to the `request.user` variable so that I can use them throughout my application and in templates?

For example, I would like to have this: `request.user.timezone` set when the user logs in to the site; I should be able to access this variable in templates and in my views.

Comment: How are you detecting the timezone? You could either use cookies, session or modify request middleware or contribute to a profile if you're just working with authenticated users.

Comment: The user sets the timezone in their profile, in the `Profile` model. Its just an example though; I want to set `request.user.x`, x being any value, when the user logs in to the site.

Can I just do `request.user.x = "value"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you like to let the user change it time-zone and force a specific time-zone ? I assume you would, if so you would like to keep the timezone configurable in your database. Therfore I would suggest you to make a UserProfile model which has one to one relations with the User Object.

You can do :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    time_zone = models.whateverField()
    ... add anything else you would like to extend your profile ...
```

On your templete you will be able to get the timezone by doing that :

```
{{ request.user.userprofile.time_zone }}
```

Simple and very clean.

If you would like to have an automatic creation of your userprofile whenever you save a User object, you can use signals for that.

Answer (score 5):

You can write a simple middleware:

```
class UserTZMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            request.user.timezone = evaluate_tz()
```

and then append this into `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in your `settings.py` file:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ....,
    'myapp.UserTZMiddleware',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the request context processor to your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS. This processor adds the  request to the context, in your template you can do {{request}} or {{ request.user }}

see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request

Answer (score 0):

Use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/?from=olddocs/), which are designed to keep variables in the context.

You should not change `request.user` as this is something that other applications will rely on and one that is populated by django's own auth machinery.

If you need to keep track of the timezone specifically, you should read up on the [timezone support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/) in django 1.4. In the documentation it provides examples for setting and managing timezones for users.